# Round up high digit numbers to halfway 10k (15k and 25k)

Tags: r, rounding

I am trying to round the following high digit to something specific.

```
lowboundx = 14400
```

I currently use either one of the following code lines but it appears to round it down all the time to something like 10k.

```
seq1x <- round(lowboundx, digits = -(trunc(log10(abs(lowboundx))))) #outcome = 10000 
seq2x <- round(lowboundx, digits = - 4) #outcome = 10000
```

What I need is to round this, and any other number, to the closest round number up (so not down). So for example:

```
9999 becomes 10000 | but | 10001 becomes 15000
11000 becomes 15000
14400 becomes 15000
17760 becomes 20000 and so on...
```

I know trunc is being used to round things down to the next logical number, but is there a way to reverse this and make it go up?
Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_numbers <- c(9999, 11000, 14400, 17760)
ceiling(my_numbers / 5000) * 5000
#[1] 10000 15000 15000 20000
```

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes you've got integers, and want the first one or two significant figures

```
x <- c(9999, 10000, 10001, 11000, 14400, 17760)

digits <- floor(log10(x)) + 1
scale_factor <- 5 * 10^(pmax(0, digits-2))

scale_factor*ceiling(x/scale_factor )

#10000 10000 15000 15000 15000 20000
```